# The top banner image not displaying in Chrome unlike in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, http-status-code-404

In the [book review](http://sreejishlals.com/accomplish-more.html), the top right banner image is not displaying in Google Chrome.

Sometimes, in Chrome, the main top wide image is also not displaying.
But, at the same time, there are no display issues in Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer. Also, in other Chrome Accounts of mine, there are no display issues. The cache was cleared in all browsers.

The error message in the console of Chrome and also in Internet explorer is

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) (icon.png:1) and the same error message for (favicon.ico:1)

`icon.png` was called in the style as can be seen in the page source of the web page. But, there is no image, `icon.png` in this theme I bought.

And I cannot see any error messages in Mozilla Firefox.
How can I fix this issue?

[Not Displaying Properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx0Vy.png)
[Displaying Properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDjCF.png)

Comment: It works fine for me. What is the resolution it reproduces in? Also have you stopped all addons in chrome. There might be some that affects the layout of your site.

Comment: Thanks @kamentk. I disabled my Chrome ad blocker extension and then it worked fine. Need I not worry about the error messages in the console?

Comment: It's a good idea to see what collides with the adblocker and fix this since your users may have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks kamentk. Good point. I guessed that the usage of "Banner ad" as the alt of image was causing the issue. I had to remove the class with the name "Banner ad" encompassing the image as well to fix this issue with Adblock plus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kamentk suggested, I disabled my Chrome ad blocker extension and then it worked fine. I am still not sure whether I can ignore the error messages in the console though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a banner covering up the account selection portion of my PSEG login and I could not get around it. Even when I right clicked and looked at Inspect on my Windows 10 PC, there did not appear to be anyway around the misplaced banner. In the Inspect it is a div class footer or maybe header. In any case when I disabled the Adblock Plus and WebBoost for the PSEG website site and refreshed twice it went away. So all is good